# Converting a city name to coordinates in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-maps

I saw few questions on SO but all of them are old in Swift 2.
I got this function from Apple website to convert a city name to latitude and longitude but I am not sure what the function will return (since there is nothing after return statement) and what should I pass. Would someone explain it a lil or show me how to use it please.

```
func getCoordinate( addressString : String, 
        completionHandler: @escaping(CLLocationCoordinate2D, NSError?) -> Void ) {
    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    geocoder.geocodeAddressString(addressString) { (placemarks, error) in
        if error == nil {
            if let placemark = placemarks?[0] {
                let location = placemark.location!

                completionHandler(location.coordinate, nil)
                return
            }
        }

        completionHandler(kCLLocationCoordinate2DInvalid, error as NSError?)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it as follow:

```
import CoreLocation

func getCoordinateFrom(address: String, completion: @escaping(_ coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D?, _ error: Error?) -> () ) {
    CLGeocoder().geocodeAddressString(address) { completion($0?.first?.location?.coordinate, $1) }
}
```

Usage:

```
let address = "Rio de Janeiro, Brazil"

getCoordinateFrom(address: address) { coordinate, error in
    guard let coordinate = coordinate, error == nil else { return }
    // don't forget to update the UI from the main thread
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        print(address, "Location:", coordinate) // Rio de Janeiro, Brazil Location: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -22.9108638, longitude: -43.2045436)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing an asynchronous operation like fetching the coordinates of a city can't return a value as the function result. You have to make the call, go about your business, and wait for it to call your completion handler. That what the parameter `completionHandler` is in the code above. You pass in a closure (a block of code) to be executed once the results are ready. You'd use it like this:

```
getCoordinate(addressString: someString) { coordinate, error in
  if error != nil {
    //display error
    return
  } else {
    //at this point `coordinate ` contains a valid coordinate. 
    //Put your code to do something with it here
    print("resulting coordinate = (\(coordinate.latitude),\(coordinate.longitude))")
  }
}
```

Note that for Swift 3, you'd make your function throw rather than returning either a result or an error.

Comment: I really appreciate what you did, but what if I just want to pass a city name to get the location since I am not sure how to use it for passing block of code. Would you please show me the exact code I need to use and I would be grateful.

Comment: The piece of code you wrote, I was not sure if it is for explanation or a real function, I tried to put it in my code and I got many errors.

Comment: The main issue here it is just a missing closing bracket which explains why the OP got many errors. Btw naming a CLLocationCoordinate2D location is misleading and you also forgot to mention that when calling an async method OP needs to go back to the main thread to update the UI.