# Returning after calling completion handler, or return completion handler parameter?

Tags: swift, asynchronous, completionhandler

I have a method that can be summed up to look like this:

```
func apply(username: String, email: String, password: String,
           onDone: @escaping (_ error: Error?) -> ())
{
    //Do async stuff
    do
    {
        try asyncGood()
        onDone(nil)
        return
    }
    catch
    {
        onDone(error)
        return
    }
}
```

What's the difference between doing:

```
return onDone(error)
```

versus

```
onDone(error)
return
```

?
Does it just save an extra line of code? I don't see any difference between the two. Am I missing some fundamental aspect of asynchronous Swift programming?

In your opinion, should I always try to condense everything down such that onDone(...) only gets called *once* at the end?

Comment: Many people are saying return statements aren't necessary at all, and I get that. But when there are multiple code paths that call `onDone(...)`, I've found that it gets called multiple times which calls subsequent code multiple times. So, that's why I always terminate my `onDone(...)`s with return statements out of habit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Semantically, both cases are the same. You are basically saying:

```
return ()
```

Your method is declared to return `()`, and since the `onDone` closure also returns a `()`, you can say `return onDone(error)`. The return types match.

However, I find writing them in 2 separate lines more readable:

```
// This clearly shows that you are doing 2 separate things
onDone(error) // call the completion handler
return // return
```

Or even omit the `return`!

```
onDone(error)
// there will be an implicit return at the end of the method.
```

Answer (score 1):

Both are same. `apply` function return type is `Void` and `onDone` closure return type is also `Void`. So both are same.

```
return onDone(error)
```

or

```
onDone(error)
return
```

or you can just ignore return because return type is `Void`

```
onDone(error)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference. In fact, there is no need for `return` keyword at all.

For swift all the following declaration is equivalent:

```
func doNothing() {
}

func doNothing2() -> Void {
}

func doNothing3() -> () {
}

func doNothing4() {
    return ()
}

func doNothing5() -> Void {
    return ()
}
```

When you return () you return nothing. No return is exactly the same as return nothing. Functions returning `Void` may be equivalently used as following

```
doNothing()

var result = doNothing()
```

More, `Void` can also be used as a type parameter which is a very powerful feature:

```
func genericCall<T>(_ f: () -> T) -> T {
    return f()
}

var result1 = genericCall { print("test") } // result1 is Void
var result2 = genericCall { return 5 } // result2 is Int
```

Answering your initial question, I would suggest to omit return at all

```
func doStuffAsync(_ callback: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
    // Just an example. Could be any other async call.
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        do {
            try doStuff()
            callback(nil)
        }
        catch {
            callback(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that generally async methods would also return an optional object along with the optional error.

Comment: If it is so bad why would Apple use it in URLSession methods?

Comment: I disagree about "bad design"

Comment: You can just return both optional objects one of them will be nil

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47244532/converting-a-city-name-to-coordinates-in-swift/47245036#47245036

Comment: Using a do try catch with a method that doesn't even throws is pointless

Comment: This is a "bad design"

Comment: In my opinion it should either throw or return an error not both.

Comment: So change your `do {
        try doAsyncStuff()` example