# How to find which country a city is in? (preferably on Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, timezone, locale

I have a list of cities and want to return the country flag. The list of cities comes from all the timezones available in Swift, so they're strings in the format Continent/CityName.

I can generate the struct Locale, or NSLocale, but their countryCode property is optional and is returning nil.

Should I manually generate a dict for all those cities and countries, or is there anywhere in Foundation or SwiftUI that I could find this info?

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to find a public Rest API for this.

Comment: can you find coordinates for this city?

Comment: I've found the coordinates [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47244532/converting-a-city-name-to-coordinates-in-swift), and then managed to transform them into Placemarks, but that didn't work for most of the cities that are actually timezones in Swift. + `CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { placemarks, error -> Void in
                guard let placeMark = placemarks?.first else { return }`